# Python imports and celery worker

Tags: python-3.x, celery, relative-import

I have the following dir structure:

```
.
└── package
    ├── foo
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── foo.py
    ├── run.py
    └── tasks.py
```

## foo/foo.py

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def double(x):
        return 2 * x
```

## run.py

```
from package.foo.foo import Foo

def do_bar(x):
    return x + 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    r1 = foo.double(10)
    r2 = do_bar(5)
    print(r1 + r2)
```

## tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery

from package.foo.foo import Foo
from package.run import do_bar

celapp = Celery('foo', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')


@celapp.task
def run():
    foo = Foo()
    foo.double(10) + do_bar(5)
```

When I run celery with `$ celery -A tasks worker` it gives me:

```
Error: 
Unable to load celery application.
The module package was not found.
```

If I only do in `tasks.py`

```
from .foo.foo import Foo
from .run import do_bar
```

I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

I think my imports are wrong but I can't get my head around how Python deals with imports.

Comment: Try start with parent directory of `package` like `from parent_dir.package.foo.foo import Foo`

Comment: @Tserenjamts I'm not sure this works.

Comment: `package` is not a package if it doesn't contain a `__init__.py`

Comment: @L3viathan even if I add an `__init__.py` it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try running `$ celery -A package.tasks worker` from the parent directory of `package` - python scripts are not meant to be run from inside the package

Answer (score 0):

As @Mr_and_Mrs_D said in their comment:

Try running `$ celery -A package.tasks worker` from the parent directory of package - python scripts are not meant to be run from inside the package

Worked wonders for me!